# pyspark RDD expand a row to multiple rows

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have the following RDD in pyspark and I believe this should be really simple to do but haven't been able to figure it out:

```
information = [ (10, 'sentence number one'),
                (17, 'longer sentence number two') ]

rdd = sc.parallelize(information)
```

I need to apply a transformation that turns that RDD into this:

```
[ ('sentence', 10),
  ('number', 10),
  ('one', 10),
  ('longer', 17),
  ('sentence', 17),
  ('number', 17),
  ('two', 17) ]
```

Basically expand a sentence key, into multiple rows with the words as keys.

**I would like to avoid SQL.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `flatMap`:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(w, x[0]) for w in x[1].split()])
```

*Example*:

```
rdd.flatMap(lambda x: [(w, x[0]) for w in x[1].split()]).collect()
# [('sentence', 10), ('number', 10), ('one', 10), ('longer', 17), ('sentence', 17), ('number', 17), ('two', 17)]
```

Comment: Excelent! Short, simple, understandable!